# gsub error turning upper to lower case in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I would like to recode some identifiers, from upper case to lower case.

I am not sure what the issue is here.

```
n = c('AFD.434', 'BSD.23', 'F234.FF')
gsub(pattern = '[[:upper:]]', replacement = '[[:lower:]]', n)

[1] "[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]].434" "[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]].23"  "[[:lower:]]234.[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]"
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you want all the upper case to be lower, use `tolower` function instead.

Comment: Just to provide you a minimum example:

   text <- "ASD.123";
tolower(text);
    [1] "asd.123"

Comment: @user3710546 this doesn't work if your string also has characters that R doesn't know how to "lower": `tolower("Ayam Penyet Ria \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb0\x94")`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your gsub call replaces each occurrence with the literal string "[[:lower:]]".

The simplest solution is to not use regular expressions; simply use `tolower()` (as already mentioned in the comments / other answers).

One possible approach with regular expressions is the usage of Perl extended mode and the `\L` modifier to convert to lowercase:

```
gsub(pattern = '([[:upper:]])', perl = TRUE, replacement = '\\L\\1', n)
```

This approach

- uses a capturing group `(...)` to "remember" the match
- uses a backreference `\1` to refer to the match in the replacement string
- uses the `\L` modifier to convert the match to lowercase

See the online help for `gsub` for further details.

Comment: Good hint, when we have to turn some parts of our data lowercase, this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: Just for the record. I had a similar problem, but in the opposite direction: greping a lower-case pattern to replace by an upper-case.  In my case pattern and replacement becomes '([[:lower]])' and '\\U\\1', respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The [`gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) function takes a regular expression as the first argument, and a replacement string as a second one that **cannot have special characters/classes that are used in a regular expression**. They are rather treated as literals. Thus, you are trying to replace each uppercase letter with a literal string `[[:lower:]]` (see [my demo](https://ideone.com/oLxNLi)).

To turn the values of your data frame to lower case, you must use [`tolower()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html) (as already have been pointed out):

```
n = c('AFD.434', 'BSD.23', 'F234.FF')
tolower(n)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/lpgPFP)

Output:

```
[1] "afd.434" "bsd.23"  "f234.ff"
```

Note that Franks's suggestion to use Perl `\L` operator is handy when we need to capitalize specific parts of the string, but in your case it seems to be an unnecessary overhead.