# Unexpected results when using regex to change case

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to change the case of a character using regex and the `stringr` package, but I'm getting a curious result. I would expect both expressions below to give the same result (capitalizing the first character), but only the `grep` function gives the expected result:

```
> str_replace("will", "(^\\w)", regex("\\U\\1"))
[1] "1ill"
> gsub("(^\\w)", "\\U\\1", "will", perl = TRUE)
[1] "Will"
```

Related:

[gsub error turning upper to lower case in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664444/gsub-error-turning-upper-to-lower-case-in-r)

Comment: you can also have a look at `Hmisc::capitalize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` uses a kind of a PCRE regex (note [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) regex does not allow case changing operators `\L` / `\l` and `\U` / `\u` with `\E`, but R extends their functionality like in [*Boost library*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html) that supports those operators).

[*stringr* library](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr) uses [ICU regex library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) and there is no support for these case changing operators, and the support was not added to the original library functionality.