# Modify the replacement value of a regex match in R

Tags: r, regex, replace

I have been working with PDFs in R and the data has been presented in a variety of formats.  I wanted to convert the data to a final data frame; it is in `chr` format now.  The easiest way to get this into a data frame is to split on the whitespace and then upload it.  All of the data looks like the following; 611 items in a long string.

[image]

```
2019-02-05 1-02/05/2019-123456-A  Thorton, Billy Bob         W123455834   XXX-XX-1776 ALEXANDER      HAMILTON
2019-02-08 1-02/08/2019-876543-B  Dern, Laura         P98765432   XXX-XX-1789 BETSY      ROSS
```

The data in the format above poses some problems:

1. The space between Billy Bob will cause an additional split in the
   data; we just have one name field.  Once those are joined, we can remove the comma easily.
2. There is a varying degree of whitespace between splits.
3. The other codes are alpha numeric.

In this post, I'll show you some regex code and tips, such as groupings, changing case, and look backs to specific groups by using the Perl extended mode:

1. Create one name out of Billy Bob
2. Convert only the names to lowercase for additional ease of processing later. If we wanted it all lowercase, then just use the `tolower()` function.

The solution was based on this post, I am expanding it to make it more generic:
[gsub error turning upper to lower case in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664444/gsub-error-turning-upper-to-lower-case-in-r)

Comment: Looking at this I suspect the sepatator is the tab character. Try reading with `sep="\t"`

Comment: It was not, it was varying amounts and I tried that right away.

Comment: Another idea would be to use pdftools-pkg: `Package: pdftools\n
Type: Package\n
Title: Text Extraction, Rendering and Converting of PDF Documents\n
Version: 2.3`

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to join all occurrences of two names (Billy Bob, Jimmie Sue, etc.) into one name so that we get `Thorton,BillyBob` and then we can split on whitespace.

The pattern that we are looking for is `lowercase space Uppercase`. The regex for this is the following:

```
pattern = stringr::regex("([a-z])( )([A-Z][a-z])")
data_join = gsub(pattern=pattern, replacement='\\1\\3', x=data, perl=TRUE)
```

We use the `()` in the regex to make three groupings: one for each element of the match.
When using the `gsub()`, by specifying the `replace='\\1\\3'`, we tell the regex to look back and use the 1st and 3rd element of the regex as replacement and skip the second which is the space making the join.

To make all the names lowercase, we need to exclude the letters in the alphanumerics as well as the '`XXX`' patterns.

```
pattern_low = stringr::regex("(([A-z]){2,}[^XXX-XX-])")
data_low = gsub(pattern=pattern_low, perl = T, replacement ='\\L\\1', x=data_join)
```

Parsing the regex: The `([A-z]){2,}` portion looks for a least two letters together to handle the alphanumeric issue.  The `[^XXX-XX-]` tells it to exclude those instances of `X`s.  Also, we add an additional set of `()` around it all to make it one group.

In the replacement we use the `\\L` to specify lower and the `\\1` to make it apply to the whole group.  I tried multiple groupings as in the first case and it did not work as well.

Now we can split and load it into a data frame:

```
# put it in a data frame
df_all = data_low %>% strsplit(split = "\\s+")
```

Adding the `+` allows it to handle varying whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Lines` in the Note at the end, read it into `L`, replace repeated spaces with a single space and then use `strcapture` with the indicated pattern. Note that `\d` matches a digit, `\D` matches a non-digit and `\S` matches a non-whitespace character. No packages are used.

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
L <- gsub("  +", " ", L)

pat <- "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (.*) (\\D\\d+) (\\S+) (\\S.*)$"
strcapture(pat, L, proto = list(date = character(0), 
  key = character(0), name1 = character(0), driver = character(0), 
  code = character(0), name2 = character(0)))
```

giving:

```
        date                   key              name1     driver        code
1 2019-02-05 1-02/05/2019-123456-A Thorton, Billy Bob W123455834 XXX-XX-1776
2 2019-02-08 1-02/08/2019-876543-B        Dern, Laura  P98765432 XXX-XX-1789
               name2
1 ALEXANDER HAMILTON
2         BETSY ROSS
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "2019-02-05 1-02/05/2019-123456-A  Thorton, Billy Bob         W123455834   XXX-XX-1776 ALEXANDER      HAMILTON
2019-02-08 1-02/08/2019-876543-B  Dern, Laura         P98765432   XXX-XX-1789 BETSY      ROSS"
```